# Quiz with lifelines

Tags: python, python-3.x, quiz

The following code is of a quiz. Is there any way to generalize the code further?

Example: If lifelines are used once, I've to a copy the code check the correct user each time. the same is for skipping. Is there any way to improve it?

```
instructions = '''                      Welcome to Py Quiz\n
      1. Each Question Carries 25k Rupees.Totally 11 questions\n
      2. One lifeline is allotted for the entire quiz.Lifelines and be used by entering 'help'\n
         a) Double Dip [ Player will be given a second chance for answering ]\n
         Important Note:Please DO NOT USE ANY OTHER KEYS OTHER THAN SPECIFIED\n
      3. Incorrect answer in any question will lead to losing the entire game\n
      4. Enjoy The Game\n'''
print(instructions)
name = input("Enter your name\n")
print(f"\n\nHi {name}!! Welcome to Py Quiz\nBest of Luck!!\n")
d = {}
points = 0
count=1
quiz = [
    {
        "question": "Which one of these is floor division?",
        "options": ["//", "%", "/", "None of the above"],
    },
    {
        "question": "Who played the role of 'Iron Man' in The Avengers series ?",
        "options": ['Robert Downey,Jr', "Chris Evans", "Chris Hemsworth", "Brie Larson"],
    },
    {
        "question": "Of the 26 World Heritage Sites identified by UNESCO in India, how many are in Karnataka?",
        "options": ['2', "5", "3", "1"],
    },
    {
        "question": "Which of these is India’s only supersonic cruise missile?",
        "options": ['BrahMos', "Agni V", "Prithvi II", "Chandrayaan"],

    },
    {
        "question": "Which of these scientists was inspired to make his famous discovery while on a sea voyage, in 1921?",
        "options": ['C V Raman', "Srinivasa Ramanujan", "Albert Einstien", "Nikola Tesla"],

    },
    {

        "question": "Which team won the first IPL(Indian Premier  League) title  in the year 2008?",
        "options": ['Rajasthan Royals', "Chennai Super Kings", "Mumbai Indians", "Deccan Chargers"],
    },
    {
        "question": "By which other name do we popularly know the Hertzian wave as?",
        "options": ['Radio Waves', "Sound Waves", "Matter Waves", "Light Waves"],

    },
    {
        "question": "What is the shape of the pupil of a goat’s eye?",
        "options": ['Rectangular', 'V-Shaped', "Elliptical", "Circular"],

    },
    {
        "question": "Who was the first actor to get Oscar Award",
        "options": ['Janet Gayner', "Charlie Chaplin", "Fairbanks", "Montgomery"],

    },
    {
        "question": "Beighton cup is associated with",
        "options": ['Hockey', "Volly Ball", "Rugby", "Baseball"],

    },
    {
        "question": "The Paithan (Jayakwadi) Hydro-electric project, completed with the help of Japan, is on the river",
        "options": ['Godavari', "Narmada", "Kaveri", "Ganga"],

    },
]

def double_dip():
    limit=1
    global points
    while limit < 2:
        user_input = input("Enter the option\n> ")
        if options[int(user_input) - 1] == d["options"][0]:
            # Answer is correct
            points += 25000
            print(f"Correct\n{name} has scored: {points} Rupees")
        else:
            # Answer is incorrect
            print(f"Wrong\n")
        limit += 1

print("Enter 1 to Start the quiz")
start = input()
Wrong = False
while start != '1':
    print(f"Invalid input: {start}")
    print("Enter 1 to Start the quiz")
    start = input()
if start == '1':
    for question_number, d in enumerate(quiz, 1):
        question = d["question"]
        options = sorted(d["options"])
        print(f"\n#{question_number}: {question}")
        for option_no, o in enumerate(options, 1):
            print(f"{option_no}: {o}")
        while True:
            user_input = input("Enter the option\n> ")
            # Valid input
            if user_input.isdecimal() and int(user_input) in list(range(1, len(options) + 1)):
                # Check answer
                if options[int(user_input) - 1] == d["options"][0]:
                    # Answer is correct
                    points += 25000
                    print(f"Correct\n{name} has scored: {points} Rupees")
                    break
                else:
                    # Answer is incorrect
                    print(f"Wrong\n{name} has scored: {points} Rupees")
                    Wrong = True
                    break
            elif user_input == 'help':
                print(f"Double Dip Activated")
                if count==1:
                    a = double_dip()
                elif count!=1:
                    print(f"No Lifelines available")
                    user_input = input("Enter the option\n> ")
                    # Valid input
                    if user_input.isdecimal() and int(user_input) in list(range(1, len(options) + 1)):
                        # Check answer
                        if options[int(user_input) - 1] == d["options"][0]:
                            # Answer is correct
                            points += 25000
                            print(f"Correct\n{name} has scored: {points} Rupees")
                            break
                        else:
                            # Answer is incorrect
                            print(f"Wrong\n{name} has scored: {points} Rupees")
                            Wrong = True
                            break
                    break
                count += 1
            elif user_input== 'skip':
                print(f"{name} Are you sure you want to skip a Question\n")
                q_input=input(f"Press Y for Yes\nPress N for No\n")
                if q_input=='Y'or 'y':
                    print(f"{name} has scored: {points} Rupees\n")
                    break
                elif q_input=='N'or 'n':
                    user_input = input("Enter the option\n> ")
                    # Valid input
                    if user_input.isdecimal() and int(user_input) in list(range(1, len(options) + 1)):
                        # Check answer
                        if options[int(user_input) - 1] == d["options"][0]:
                            # Answer is correct
                            points += 25000
                            print(f"Correct\n{name} has scored: {points} Rupees")
                            break
                        else:
                            # Answer is incorrect
                            print(f"Wrong\n{name} has scored: {points} Rupees")
                            Wrong = True
                            break
                else:
                    print(f"Invalid User input {q_input}\n")

            else:
                print(f"Invalid input: {user_input}\n{name} has scored: {points} Rupees")
                Wrong = True
                break
        # Breaking loop if answer is incorrect
        if Wrong:
            break
```

Comment: Why should any other option be compared with the 1st one: `if options[int(user_input) - 1] == d["options"][0]:` ?

Comment: Because d['options'][0] is the correct answer

Comment: For future questions, the title should indicate what the code does, and not what you want to get out of the question. A good title might be `Quiz`.